# How to create superscript type of TextView as shown in image

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

i want to create a Textview like this image in android. Is it possible to create this in a single text view .[image]

Comment: You can use html tags to get this text in single textview.

Comment: @ subrahmanyam boyapati : i tried this already, but that is not giving me the same result.

Comment: ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("102<sup>60</sup>")); try above way

Comment: check my updated answer. Works fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this question being pending for so long here is my solution, i solved this by using two different size TextViews in constraint layout. no other solution is worked for me.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/balance_amount_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="107"
            android:textSize="94sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dollar_tv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/balance_superscript_amount_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="2.5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/balance_amount_tv"
            android:text="50"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/balance_amount_tv"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/balance_amount_tv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/balance_amount_tv"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try below way to achieve superscript in textview

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("102<sup>60</sup>"));
```

Comment: 60 is going above 102 which is not the case, both 102 and 60 should be top aligned.

Comment: Add 120 inside <sup> tag

Comment: hey can you tell me exactly what you are expecting?

Comment: you need 102 as bold?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126819/discussion-between-sunil-kushwah-and-subrahmanyam-boyapati).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
Try Spannable String like this:

```
 SpannableString styledString = new SpannableString("10260");

 // superscript
    styledString.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 3, 5, 0);

   // Give the styled string to a TextView
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    textView.setText(styledString);
```